# Jenkins Email notifications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to figure out how to add the Cause and Changes tokens to the body of an email notification.

I have tried different tokens (with and without brackets} like:

```
Causes: ${BUILD.CAUSES}
${CAUSE}
${CAUSES}
```

But these do not resolve to anything other than what you see there. Is there a token I am missing? Maybe a syntax issue?

I have the emails set up as plain text. The project tokens work as expected. Here is what is in the body for Default Content currently:

```
$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:

Cause: ${CAUSE}

Branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}

Commit Id: ${GIT_COMMIT}

Change: ${CHANGES}

${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=30, escapeHtml=true}
```